# NetValidatePasswordPolicy is not evaluating password complexity rules but only length

Tags: c#, c++, validation, passwords, complexity-theory

I am trying to evaluate if password complexity rules are met using the NetValidatePasswordPolicy API.
I have found many samples for this, but not one of them is working for me.

I have tried different ways of using the API with `NetValidatePasswordReset` and `NetValidatePasswordChange` Parameter but the result is always the same.

My problem is, that the API only just tests for password length. If the password is too short I get the error 2245 (which means the password is to short), but when I enter a longer password which does not meet the complexity rules at all I get a success code back (instead of `PasswordNotComplexEnough`).

Did anyone get this API function work? Please help and thanks for your support.

Below is the code that doesn't work. I tried it on two different systems. One is Windows 8 connected to an Active Directory domain. The other is a domain server of the same domain (running with Windows Server 2008 R2).

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h> 
#include <lm.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <vcclr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib") 

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace PasswordPolicyCheck {


    public ref class srPasswordValidator 
    { 
    //public : static const int PasswordValidationSuccess = NERR_Success;
    //public: static const int PasswordAccountLockedOut = NERR_AccountLockedOut;
    //public: static const int PasswordTooRecent = NERR_PasswordTooRecent;
    //public: static const int PasswordBadPassword = NERR_BadPassword;
    //public: static const int PasswordHistConfilct = NERR_PasswordHistConflict;
    //public: static const int PasswordTooShort = NERR_PasswordTooShort;
    //public: static const int PasswordTooLong = NERR_PasswordTooLong;
    //public: static const int PasswordNotComplexEnough = NERR_PasswordNotComplexEnough;
    //public: static const int PasswordFlterError = NERR_PasswordFilterError;

        public :int ValidatePassword(String^ userName, String^ password, String^ domainController) 
        { 

            LPWSTR wzPwd = static_cast<LPWSTR>(Marshal::StringToBSTR(password).ToPointer()); 
            LPWSTR wzUser = static_cast<LPWSTR>(Marshal::StringToBSTR(userName).ToPointer()); 
            LPWSTR  wzServer = static_cast<LPWSTR>(Marshal::StringToBSTR(domainController).ToPointer()); 

            NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG* Output = NULL; 
            NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_RESET_INPUT_ARG Input = {0}; 
            //NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG Input = {0}; 

            Input.ClearLockout = true;
            Input.PasswordMustChangeAtNextLogon = false;
            Input.UserAccountName = wzUser;
            Input.ClearPassword = wzPwd;
            //Input.PasswordMatch = TRUE;

            /*NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HASH PasswordHistory;
            size_t lLength = wcslen(wPassword);
            PasswordHistory.Length = lLength;
            PasswordHistory.Hash = new BYTE[lLength];
            memcpy(PasswordHistory.Hash, wPassword, lLength);
            Input.HashedPassword = PasswordHistory;
            Input.InputPersistedFields.PresentFields = NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HISTORY | NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HISTORY_LENGTH;*/

            DWORD dwErr = NetValidatePasswordPolicy (wzServer, NULL, _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE::NetValidatePasswordReset, &Input, (void **) &Output); 
            int ReturnValue = Output->ValidationStatus;
            NetValidatePasswordPolicyFree ((void **) &Output); 
            return ReturnValue;
        } 
    }; 

}
```